search for all string except new line characters and last string
I have an output that expecting characters before a final string statement such as so:
\ntest
\n
\n{master}

I want to capture anything except the new line characters \n and {master}. For example, this should fail:
\n
\n
\n{master}

I've tried this (?!\n)\w*(?:{master}) and it keeps matching master... any help is appreciated!

Why are you using regular expressions?

I'd be tempted to instead omit those substrings and see what's left
content.replace("{master}", "").replace("\n", "")

>>> content = """\ntest
... \n
... \n{master}"""
>>> content.replace("{master}", "").replace("\n", "")
'test'

while it seems unlikely in your case, do take some caution in ordering the replacements to at least avoid mashing two lines to form a new substring (such as \n{mas\nter}

Thanks, this is probably better.
